# Как вытянуть лайки?

Tags: php, парсер, вконтакте, curl, like

index.php

```
<?php
include_once('libs/SQL.php');
include_once('libs/curl_query.php');
include_once('libs/simple_html_dom.php');


$html = curl_get('https://vk.com/mudachyo');
$dom = str_get_html($html);
$courses = $dom->find('.post_date');

foreach ($courses as $cours){
    $a = $cours->find('a',0);
    $url = str_replace('/','',$a->href);

    $one = curl_get('https://vk.com/mudachyo?w='.$url);
    $one_dom = str_get_html($one);
   $like = $one_dom->find('.post_full_like',0);
   echo $like->plaintext.'<br>';
}
```

simple_html_dom.php

```
<?php
    function curl_get($url, $refer = 'http://www.google.com'){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36");
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        $data=curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
}
```

Выводит:

```
4,215 Show likes 79 Show shared copies 
4,215 Show likes 79 Show shared copies 
4,215 Show likes 79 Show shared copies 
4,215 Show likes 79 Show shared copies 
4,215 Show likes 79 Show shared copies 
4,215 Show likes 79 Show shared copies 
4,215 Show likes 79 Show shared copies 
4,215 Show likes 79 Show shared copies 
4,215 Show likes 79 Show shared copies 
4,215 Show likes 79 Show shared copies
```

Как сделать так что бы парсело другие блоки а не один и тот же?
Что то в этом роде.Пример:

```
 4,215 Show likes 79 Show shared copies 
    637   Show likes 79 Show shared copies 
    220 Show likes 79 Show shared copies 
    520 Show likes 79 Show shared copies 
    840 Show likes 79 Show shared copies 
    700 Show likes 79 Show shared copies 
    900 Show likes 79 Show shared copies
```

Comment: Например воспользоваться API можно и не извращаться

Comment: @АлексейШиманский можно и так пришло в голову это когда уже написал код.Но интересно можно ли получить данные таким способом?